# Modify current Object and not prefab

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm really new to unity, This is my first project.
My problem is than when I create a new gameobject

> public GameObject fancyName;

and then drag the prefab I want over the script window, if I make any changes on fancyName, instead of modifying what I see on the screen I get to modify my prefab...
What do I have to do in order to modify the Instantiate GameObject and not the prefab?

Comment: Instantiate and grab a reference to that instantiated gameobject, something like `GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(fancyName, pos, rot)`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my proble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an expected behavior because `fancyName` holds a reference to your prefab so any changes you make to 'fancyName' is a direct modification to your prefab (remember you dragged & dropped your prefab to this variable right?).

You should instantiate/clone it:

```
var clone = (GameObject) Instantiate(fancyName);
```

and then

`MakeChange(clone); // Do anything you want`